# How to write the sound of a pool break

Tags: onomatopoeia

I am trying to write the sound of a pool break. Something like "thwock", but I need some input to capture it best.

Comment: There's a nice website called WrittenSound.com (an Onomatopoeia dictionary) that doesn't have that exactly named sound but lots of others to explore for inspiration! http://writtensound.com/index.php?term=t

Comment: Does _crack_ sound right to you?

Comment: What kind of pool?

Comment: This is not a question that really has a definitive answer--it will be people's opinions that you'll get. @KristinaLopez's link sounds like a good place to look so you can form your own opinion.

Comment: The writers if the batsman tv series